# Fixed position of main content with scrollable menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have the following page (based on david bushell off canvas responsive menu):

http://kwedsd.byethost7.com/test.html

it shows a responsive menu (not completely working properly), when you shrink the width of the browser the three horizontal line icon will be visible. When you click on it, the menu slides in, and this is where I have the problem, as all the links are not visible.

Firstly I would like the menu items to be listed all the way down the page and not restricted to the height of the main content. Secondly I would like to freeze the main content and just have the menu scrollable (if you refer to http://disney.com/?intoverride=true this is an example of what I would like to achieve when the menu is clicked the main content freezes but the menu is still scrollable).

I have tried setting position fixed to the main content which did not work. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the "overflow" value on #nav to "scroll".  So your CSS would read:

```
#nav { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 5.25em;
  overflow: scroll;
  etc......
}
```

By having overflow:scroll, you at least give your user the ability to scroll through your menu list.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to make a lot of changes to your css, too many to effectively list here and enough that it made testing this out myself in full not terribly easy.

The main goal here is to make the list have a real height, with an absolute position the element is sort of ignored in the layout.

Remove the `translate3d` properties which are on the `#nav` and `#main` elements and make the `#nav` float left instead. You'll then have to play around with the overflow, width, and probably a number of other properties on the `#main` element to make it display the way you wish.

Some of these will require new rules such as `#nav { width: 0; } html.js-nav #nav { width: 70%; }` so that you can make the transition when the menu is supposed to be shown.

This is a starting point, it should get you in a better position than you are now, if you get stuck further down the line, come back for more help.